# will frequent querying in srvrmgr affect the performance of Siebel application?

Tags: performance, siebel, command-line-interface

i have batch file that will start Siebel svrmgr command line interface and query some 10 list commands for every 5 mins. Will this affect the performance of the siebel application? if it so, what is the recommended interval to do this task?

Thanks,
Ramachandran

Comment: Why you are calling that list commands? Is it some kind of monitoring? What you are doing with command output?

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin yes, it is for monitoring siebel application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Frequent invocation of srvrmgr utility puts additional load on Gateway server. Though this is can be very negligible on a high performance server. But be aware that on AIX it can lead to memory leakage if proper patch is not applied.

Read Doc ID 1269177.1 on Oracle Support for more on this.

Also you should carefully choose the mechanism for using srvrmgr. Hope you find this useful.